# JS script doesn't work when i click back on site

Tags: javascript, jquery

i create a nav on my site. Navigation works good but when i back on the main site all script from js file doesn't work. Script for my nav:

```
var default_content="";
$(document).ready(function(){
//Ajax navigate
checkURL();
$('footer a').click(function(){
        checkURL(this.hash);
});
default_content = $('#login_box').html();
setInterval("checkURL()",250);
.........
```

Methods:

```
 var lasturl="";
    function checkURL(hash)
    {
        if(!hash) hash=window.location.hash;
        if(hash != lasturl)
        {
            lasturl=hash;
            if(hash=="")
            $('#login_box').html(default_content);
            else
            loadPage(hash);
        }
    }


function loadPage(url)
{
    url=url.replace('#page','');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "include/help4meApi.php",
        data: 'page='+url+'&tag=navigation',
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg){

            if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
            {
                $('#login_box').html(msg);
            }
        }

    });

}
```

Problem is when i back to the main site scripts doesn't work.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What do you mean by _it doesn't work_? Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @trucik edit this question and add your demo HTML

Comment: @Aminul http://help4me.pl/login.php click on footer "Kontakt", click backspace i click on "Zarejestruj" and nothing happnes, when you refresh page and click on "Zarejestruj" once again it works

Comment: @MelanciaUK when I go throug on nav and back on main site scirpts doesn't work. For example in help4me.pl/login.php when You click on element in footer and back on main site the "Zarejestruj" button don't work. When you refresh it works.

Comment: That is because the when you click on the back button, then browser render the DOM from its history. Try with History API to detect State of browser https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue comes from here `$('#login_box').html(default_content);`. When u calle the `.html()` the event binded within the element will be cleaned.

When you backspace, back to the main page, the event handler is already not there, so you have to register it again

```
//For show and hide register values
$("#registerInputsBtn").click(function(){
    $(".register_information").hide(1000);
    $(".register_values").show(1000);
    $("#firstname").focus();
});
```

register again on the piece of code that you assign the content to `#login_box`. For example the quick fix:

```
if(hash==""){
        $('#login_box').html(default_content);
        $("#registerInputsBtn").click(function(){
            $(".register_information").hide(1000);
            $(".register_values").show(1000);
            $("#firstname").focus();
        });
    }
```

but here the codes are not DRY :( rearrange the flow on how the page load and the register the event in the correct flow is recommended.

Comment: i don't understand, how do this?